# Basic tampering protection

Tags: c++, tampering, software-protection

I'm trying to create a basic program that has tampering protection on the licenseCheck function, however it always says it's correct, even if I nop the whole licenseCheck function in Ollydbg or change and rebuild the code.

I'm following the Surreptitious Software book, and wrote the following program:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#define HASH 5131241 

void BEGIN() {}

const std::string correctlicense("ABC");

bool licenseCheck() {

    std::cout << "Enter license: ";

    std::string license;
    std::cin >> license;

    volatile DWORD d;

    // Fingerprint
    __asm {
        lea ebx, d
        mov ebx, 0x050b072b
    }

    return license.compare(correctlicense) == 0;
}

UINT hash(UINT *beginAddress, UINT *endAddress) {

    UINT h = *beginAddress;

    for (; beginAddress <= endAddress; beginAddress++) {
        h ^= *beginAddress;
    }

    return h;
}
void END() {}


int main()
{

    UINT uHash = hash((UINT*)BEGIN, (UINT*)END);

    std::cout << "[Protection checks]" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Tampering: ";

    if (uHash != HASH) {
        std::cout << "Tampering detected! ( " << uHash << " )" << std::endl;
        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Correct" << std::endl;
    }

    if (licenseCheck()) {
        std::cout << "Correct!" << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Failed!" << std::endl;
    }


    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

The program basically 'hashes' the code between the BEGIN function and END function, but it doesn't seem to work. The hash is always correct even after tampering.

I'm using Windows 7 and Visual studio 2017 the build/run the program.

Comment: How do you tamper?

Comment: I'm using ollydbg to make the licenseCheck function always return true. I also tried to nop the whole licenseCheck function

Comment: The compiler does not necessarily arrange the functions in the order you declare them.

Comment: [removed] ah right. C++ nevermind. it's 0 on equal

Comment: foregoing my last idiotic comment, can you post the ASM dump from the compiler? Would be nice to see the ASM generated for this function

Comment: Are you building as debug or release? Try switching and you'll start seeing the problem with the approach you are using.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Are there any compiler options to control this? This example is uses the exact same method as written in the book, so I guess it should be possible

Comment: @CorvusCrypto the licenseCheck function?

Comment: @djgandy I'm building this as debug at the moment

Comment: @JeffreyZ I'm not aware of any options for this.